# How to change keys of array and keep their position with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
Array
(
    [rating1] => super-happy
    [rating2] => super-happy
    [rating3] => super-happy
    [rating4] => super-happy
    [rating5] => super-sad
)
```

And:

```
$vragen =
[
"lorem question 1",
"lorem question 2",
"lorem question 3",
"lorem question 4",
"lorem question 5",
];
```

Now in a loop that goes through the first arrays I want to use an if statement to change the keys of the first array and put a question from the second array in place. Like this:

```
$vragen =
[
"lorem question 1",
"lorem question 2",
"lorem question 3",
"lorem question 4",
"lorem question 5",
];
foreach($vragen as $vraag){
    $reviewhtml .= '<li>'.$vraag.'</li>';
    while($getreviews = $getreviewscon->fetch_assoc()){
      $ratingvragen = json_decode($getreviews['rating'], true);
      foreach($ratingvragen as $keyrating => $rating){
        if($keyrating == 'rating1'){
          $ratingvragen['lorem question 1'] = $ratingvragen[$keyrating];
        }else if($keyrating == 'rating2'){
          $ratingvragen['lorem question 2'] = $ratingvragen[$keyrating];
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But instead of replacing the keys, it adds them to the array. If I print `$ratingvragen` this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [rating1] => super-happy
    [rating2] => super-happy
    [rating3] => super-happy
    [rating4] => super-happy
    [rating5] => super-happy
    [lorem question 1] => super-happy
    [lorem question 2] => super-happy
)
```

But the desired output would be:

```
Array
(
    [lorem question 1] => super-happy
    [lorem question 2] => super-happy
    [rating3] => super-happy
    [rating4] => super-happy
    [rating5] => super-happy
)
```

Why does my code add new array entries instead of replacing the ones in my if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 foreach($ratingvragen as $keyrating => $rating){

    if($keyrating == 'rating1'){
        $newratingvragen['lorem question 1'] = $ratingvragen[$keyrating];
    }
    else if($keyrating == 'rating2'){
        $newratingvragen['lorem question 2'] = $ratingvragen[$keyrating];
    }
    else
    {
        $newratingvragen[$keyrating] = $ratingvragen[$keyrating]
    }
 }
```

`$newratingvragen` have desired output

another method instead of whole foreach

```
$keyReplaceInfoz = ['rating1' =>'lorem question 1','rating2' =>'lorem question 2','rating3'=>'rating3','rating4'=>'rating4', 'rating5'=>'rating5']

$ratingvragen = array_combine(array_merge($ratingvragen, $keyReplaceInfoz), $ratingvragen);
```

another method

```
$ratingvragen = array_combine(
    ['lorem question 1', 'lorem question 2','rating3','rating4', 'rating5'],
    array_values($ratingvragen)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ratingvragen = [
    'rating1' => [ 'key' => 'rating1', 'review' => "super-happy" ],
    'rating2' => [ 'key' => 'rating2', 'review' => "super-happy" ],
    'rating3' => [ 'key' => 'rating3', 'review' => "super-happy" ],
    'rating4' => [ 'key' => 'rating4', 'review' => "super-happy" ],
    'rating5' => [ 'key' => 'rating5', 'review' => "super-sad" ],
];

...

if($keyrating == 'rating1'){
  $ratingvragen[$keyrating]['key'] = 'lorem question 1';
}

...

print_r(array_column($ratingvragen, 'review', 'key'));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did? Your array is not what my array looks like.

Comment: I modified `$ratingvragen` as a nested to use `array_column()`. It is very handy.